# How to use multiple variables for cell formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use multiple variables to control the formula I want to enter into a certain cell. My code is:

```
Sub test()
Dim a As String, b As String, c As String

With ThisWorkbook

a = .Sheets("Share").Cells(2, 21).Address()

b = .Sheets("Share").Cells(8, 21).Address(RowAbsolute:=False)
c = .Sheets("Share").Cells(8, 23).Address(ColumnAbsolute:=False)

MsgBox a  '$U$2
MsgBox b  '$U8
MsgBox c  'W$8

.Sheets("Share").Cells(8, 23).Formula = "=SUMIFS($E8:" & b & ",$E$2:" & a & "," & c& ")"

'=SUMIFS($E8:$U8,$E$2:$U$2,W$4)

End With
End Sub
```

But it keeps giving me this error:

> Compile error: Syntax error.

Does anyone know why? I searched some topics online, but I didn't find a clear solution for that.

Comment: I made a couple of edits to clarify your question. Please note that in the future you should indicate the line that results in the compile error. The compiler will indicate the line that it thinks is a problem, so it's good practice to let us know which line it identified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space between `c` and the following `&` in this line:

```
.Sheets("Share").Cells(8, 23).Formula = "=SUMIFS($E8:" & b & ",$E$2:" & a & "," & c & ")"
```

When you leave the space out, as in `c&`, the compiler misinterprets the `&` as an [identifier type character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters) instead of as the concatenation operator.